# Compare Byte Arrays Before Saving To Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, file-io, arrays

What is the best way of comparing that my image saved to a database isnt different, thus saving I/O.

**Scenario:**

Im writing an ASP.NET Application in MVC3 using Entity Framework. I have an *Edit* action method for my UserProfile Controller. Now i want to check that the image i have posted back to the method is different, and if it is, then i want to call the ObjectContext .**SaveChanges()** if it is the same image, then move on.

Here is a cut down version of my code:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userprofile, HttpPostedFileBase imageLoad2)
    {
        Medium profileImage = new Medium();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (imageLoad2 != null)
                {
                    if ((db.Media.Count(i => i.Unique_Key == userprofile.Unique_Key)) > 0)
                    {
                        profileImage = db.Media.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Unique_Key == userprofile.Unique_Key);
                        profileImage.Amend_Date = DateTime.Now;
                        profileImage.Source = Images.ImageToBinary(imageLoad2.InputStream);
                        profileImage.File_Size = imageLoad2.ContentLength;
                        profileImage.File_Name = imageLoad2.FileName;
                        profileImage.Content_Type = imageLoad2.ContentType;
                        profileImage.Height = Images.FromStreamHeight(imageLoad2.InputStream);
                        profileImage.Width = Images.FromStreamWidth(imageLoad2.InputStream);

                        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(profileImage, EntityState.Modified);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So i save my image as a varbinary(max) in nto a SQL Server Express DB, which is referenced as a byte array in my entities.

Is it just a case of looping around the byte array from the post and comparing it to the byte array pulled back into the ObjectContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than directly comparing the byte array, I would compare the hash of the images. Perhaps something like the following could be extracted into a comparison method:

```
SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
byte[] imgHash1 = sha.ComputeHash(imgBytes1);
byte[] imgHash2 = sha.ComputeHash(imgBytes2);

// compare the hashes
for (int i = 0; i < imgHash1.Length && i < imgHash2.Length; i++)
{
    //found a non-match, exit the loop
    if (!(imgHash1[i] == imgHash2[i]))
        return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Enumerable.SequenceEqual http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx